# Authorization missing error when using the token as header using python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, token, basic-authentication, request-headers

Trying to convert curl below to the Python requests, below is the curl command which is working fine.

`curl -k -H "Authorization: Token token=\"$token\""https://conjur.com/secret`

Above curl works fine and gives expected output but when I turn that into python requests it is giving me trouble the header is weird not sure how to pass that, i tried below

```
token="abcdef"
token_header = {'Authorization': f'Token token={token}'}
requests.get("https://conjur.com/secret", headers=token_header).text
```

Above code gives error and looks like header is not working as expected,let me know how can i solve it ?

Already mentioned above

Comment: Can you try: `token_header = {"Authorization": f'Token token="{token}"'}`  (note the `"` around token) ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely thank you i think it goes through, really healpful

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you explain a bit more about the issue? and how quotes around token solved it

Comment: I looked at the curl command you have in your question: `curl -k -H "Authorization: Token token=\"$token\"" https://conjur.com/secret` <-- there are quotes around the token. In your Python code you're missing them... I write proper answer, not just comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your curl command you have quotes around the token:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Token token=\"$token\"" https://conjur.com/secret
```

Note the `token=\"$token\"`

---

To have quotes in your Python code do:

```py
token_header = {"Authorization": f'Token token="{token}"'}
```